# How to make json array from csv data set config using groovy script in jmeter

Tags: json, csv, groovy, jmeter

I have a Csv file with multiple records(comma Seperated), i need a groovy script that can fetch all the data's from csv and make a json array and send a POST request in jmeter. Here is my code below. But it only fetches one record

```
import groovy.json.*
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

def jsonBuilder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
jsonBuilder {
    id Integer.parseInt(vars.get("id"))
    name vars.get("first_name")
    last_name vars.get("last_name")
    email vars.get("email")
    institute_id Integer.parseInt(vars.get("institute_id"))
    category_id Integer.parseInt(vars.get("category_id"))
    value Boolean.parseBoolean(vars.get("value"))
}

sampler.addNonEncodedArgument("",jsonBuilder.toPrettyString(),"")
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
```

Comment: Could you please also post what the variable `vars` is?

Comment: vars (JMeter variables) is the most frequently used component. It's an instance of the org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables class and provides read/write access to current variables, is capable of enumerating/changing existing variables, creating new ones, and obtaining nested properties.

Comment: How the desired json would look like?

Comment: {
    "_token": "sometokentext",
    "candidate": [{
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "lorem ipsum",
        "last_name": "lorem ipsum",
        "email": "loremipsum@loremipsum.com",
        "institute_id": loremipsum,
        "category_id": loremipsum,
        "value": false
    }],

"test_id": "${id}",
 "selectedDate": "${date}"
}

Comment: I don't understand why you need groovy script at all? Why not put JSON (exactly as you posted it in the comment above) directly in the HTTP Sampler, i.e. HTTP Sampler body `{ "_token": "sometokentext", "candidate": [{ "id": 1, "first_name": "${first_name}", "last_name": "${last_name}", "email": "${email}", "institute_id": ${institute_id}, "category_id": ${category_id}, "value": ${value} }], "test_id": "${id}", "selectedDate": "${date}" }`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the following CSV file:

```
id,first_name,last_name,email,institute_id,category_id,value
1,john,doe,johndoe@example.com,1,1,true
2,jane,doe,janedoe@example.com,2,2,false
```

You can convert it into a [JSON Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) using below Groovy code:

```
    import groovy.json.JsonOutput

    def lines = new File('test.csv').readLines()

    def keys = lines[0].split(',')
    def rows = lines[1..-1].collect { line ->
        def i = 0, vals = line.split(',')
        keys.inject([:]) { map, key -> map << ["$key": vals[i++]] }
    }

    log.info(JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(rows)))
```

Demo:

[image: Groovy CSV to JSON]

References:

- [JsonOutput class reference](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.7/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonOutput.html)
- [Groovy: Parsing and Producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)